# Add Dependency to Slim 3 Framework

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I'm new using Slim 3 Framework. I want to add this dependency **faisalman/simple-excel-php**. I installed via *Composer* but I don't know how to use it in my Controller. Do I need to add it to the container?

This is my *composer.json* file:

```
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^3.8",
    "slim/php-view": "^2.2",
    "slim/twig-view": "^2.2",
    "illuminate/database": "^5.4",
    "faisalman/simple-excel-php": "^0.3.15"
},
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "App\\":"app"
    }
}
```

My project Structure is

1. App

   1.1. Controllers
2. Bootstrap

   2.1 app.php (here i instanse my app)
3. vendor

Comment: `composer require packageid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done a `composer require faisalman/simple-excel-php`, you now have the library installed in your application and available via autoload.

The next step is using it.

There is no direct need to integrate this library into the Slim DI container or worry about the bootstrap file. You can follow the example in the library's readme and instantiate directly:

```
use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel

$excel = new SimpleExcel('CSV');
$excel->parser->loadFile('test.csv');
```

in whatever file makes the most sense for your project.